# Canvas Clock should start at specific position

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to start the second hand of clock from  a specific position say 15 hrs on loading the page.

```js
function drawTime(ctx, radius){
    now = new Date();
    second = now.getSeconds();
    second=(second*Math.PI/30);
    console.log(second);
    drawHand(ctx, second, radius*0.9, radius*0.02);
  }

function drawHand(ctx, pos, length, width) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineWidth = width;
    ctx.lineCap = "round";
    ctx.moveTo(0,0);
    ctx.rotate(pos);
    ctx.lineTo(0, -(3*length/4));
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.rotate(-pos);
    ctx.restore();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've changed your code to use an arbitrary time and date. The passage of time is emulated via `setInterval()` function.

I've added some comments to make it easier to understand what's going on.

```
// The starting date. The date is arbitrary, the time is set to 15:00:00.
// .getTime() returns time in milliseconds, so it's easier to increment later on.
var currentTime = (new Date('2011-10-10T15:00:00')).getTime();

function drawTime(ctx, radius){
  var now = new Date(currentTime);
  var second = now.getSeconds();
  second = (second * Math.PI / 30);
  console.log(second);
  drawHand(ctx, second, radius * 0.9, radius * 0.02);
}

function drawHand(ctx, pos, length, width) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineWidth = width;
  ctx.lineCap = "round";
  ctx.moveTo(0,0);
  ctx.rotate(pos);
  ctx.lineTo(0, -(3*length/4));
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.rotate(-pos);
  ctx.restore();
}

// Emulating the clock. 1000 milliseconds = 1 second.
setInterval(function() {
  currentTime += 1000; 
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Thanks Victor,
But when I set the Hour/Minute/second hands,they doesn't move... they remain static..

Comment: When I set by using now.setSeconds(15), after that when I use now.getSeconds(), I get only 15 as output. The second value  doesn't increment.What I need is second value to increment every second and when I use now.getSeconds() I should get output as incremented value.

Comment: Hmm, I didn't think about that. Maybe we can emulate a clock by using `setInterval`? I'll update my answer with an example shortly

Comment: Victor, I guess we cannot increment the current time..:(